# Adding numbers across multiple files

Tags: unix, awk

If I have a few files, e.g.

File 1:

```
3 apples 
8 bananas 
4 pears
```

File 2:

```
1 bananas 
12 oranges
```

File 3:

```
3 pears 
1 strawberries
```

And I wish to tabulate a list of all fruits across all the files I have. Desired output:

```
3 apples 
9 bananas 
7 pears 
12 oranges 
1 strawberries
```

Since file 1 does not contain all the elements, does that mean I can't use awk NR==FNR?

Comment: How about concat all files into 1, and then apply an AWK function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk '{ a[$2]=a[$2]+$1;} END{ for( idx in a){ print idx,a[idx]}}' file*
```